# Can't apt-get -f install to Linux 4.4.14-eve-ng-ukms+ (EVE-NG)

Tags: linux

I have the following output error by trying to resolve apt dependencies.

```
  root@eve-ng:/usr/lib/perl5# apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6 linux-headers-4.4.0-150-generic linux-headers-generic
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-150-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6 linux-headers-generic
2 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 178 not upgraded.
29 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,385 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,605 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 3, near "0ubuntu1"
    (Missing operator before ubuntu1?)
Semicolon seems to be missing at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 3.
Unquoted string "universe" may clash with future reserved word at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 5.
debconf: Perl may be unconfigured (syntax error at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 2, near "accountwizard
Architecture:"
Unknown regexp modifier "/b" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Regexp modifier "/u" may not appear twice at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/t" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Regexp modifier "/u" may not appear twice at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/v" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/e" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/r" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/e" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/k" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
/usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm has too many errors.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver.pm line 13.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver.pm line 13.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Db.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Db.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Log.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 1) line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 1) line 4.
) -- aborting
(Reading database ... 220043 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.23-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb ...
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 3, near "0ubuntu1"
    (Missing operator before ubuntu1?)
Semicolon seems to be missing at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 3.
Unquoted string "universe" may clash with future reserved word at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 5.
syntax error at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 2, near "accountwizard
Architecture:"
Unknown regexp modifier "/b" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Regexp modifier "/u" may not appear twice at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/t" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Regexp modifier "/u" may not appear twice at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/v" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/e" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/r" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/e" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/k" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
/usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm has too many errors.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Template.pm line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Template.pm line 15.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Log.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Db.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Db.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 6.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 255
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I dont know what else to do I also applied:

```
root@eve-ng:/usr/lib/perl5# dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 220043 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.23-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb ...
Bareword found where operator expected at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 3, near "0ubuntu1"
    (Missing operator before ubuntu1?)
Semicolon seems to be missing at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 3.
Unquoted string "universe" may clash with future reserved word at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 5.
syntax error at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 2, near "accountwizard
Architecture:"
Unknown regexp modifier "/b" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Regexp modifier "/u" may not appear twice at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/t" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Regexp modifier "/u" may not appear twice at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/v" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/e" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/r" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/e" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
Unknown regexp modifier "/k" at /usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm line 9, at end of line
/usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm has too many errors.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Template.pm line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Template.pm line 15.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Question.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Config.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Log.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Db.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Db.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 6.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb (--install):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 255
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb
```

But didn't had any good result. Any sugestion on how to resolve this issue?
Seems to be a Perl problem for me.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/usr/share/perl/5.22/fields.pm` file (which is part of the `perl-modules-5.22` package) is damaged. It appears to have been replaced by a package management file.

This is troubling, and suggests that some degree of filesystem corruption has occurred. It is likely that other critical files on the system have been damaged as well; you should back up any data and reinstall the system, if possible.

Nevertheless, if you want to try to recover this system, your first step *after backing up your data* should be to reinstall `perl-modules-5.22`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to apply apt -f install and fix the dependencies by first installing the following packages.

```
dpkg -i perl-modules-5.22_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6_all.deb
dpkg -i linux-headers-4.4.0-150_4.4.0-150.176_all.deb
dpkg -i libperl5.22_5.22.1-9ubuntu0.6_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15_amd64.deb
dpkg -i linux-headers-4.4.0-150-generic_4.4.0-150.176_amd64.deb
dpkg -i libc6_2.23-0ubuntu11_amd64.deb
```

Then ran the command again and it worked!!

```
root@eve-ng:~# apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-headers-generic
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 177 not upgraded.
27 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,576 B of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 229876 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-generic_4.4.0.150.158_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (4.4.0.150.158) over (4.4.0.141.147) ...
Setting up grub-pc (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.19) ...
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.14-eve-ng-ukms+
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.14-eve-ng-ukms+
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-150-generic
done
Setting up tzdata (2018i-0ubuntu0.16.04) ...

Current default time zone: 'Europe/Riga'
Local time is now:      Sat Jun 15 01:56:23 EEST 2019.
Universal Time is now:  Fri Jun 14 22:56:23 UTC 2019.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

Setting up libsasl2-modules:amd64 (2.1.26.dfsg1-14ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libc6-dev:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Setting up libc6-i386 (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Setting up libwinpr-utils0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-pool0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-codec1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-common1.1.0:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-utils1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-crypto1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-locale1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-rpc0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libwinpr-sspi0.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-core1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-cache1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-client1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-gdi1.1:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libfreerdp-plugins-standard:amd64 (1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg1-5ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-141-generic (4.4.0-141.167) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
Setting up linux-headers-generic (4.4.0.150.158) ...
Setting up linux-headers-virtual (4.4.0.150.158) ...
Setting up linux-modules-4.4.0-150-generic (4.4.0-150.176) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-150-generic (4.4.0-150.176) ...
I: /vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-4.4.14-eve-ng-ukms+
I: /initrd.img.old is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-4.4.14-eve-ng-ukms+
I: /vmlinuz is now a symlink to boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-150-generic
I: /initrd.img is now a symlink to boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-150-generic
Setting up linux-image-virtual (4.4.0.150.158) ...
Setting up linux-virtual (4.4.0.150.158) ...
Setting up openssl (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.14) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.4.0-150-generic (4.4.0-150.176) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-150-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.14-eve-ng-ukms+
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.14-eve-ng-ukms+
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-150-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-150-generic
done
```

After that I proceed to apply an

```
apt update && apt upgrade
```

with no errors.